# How can I install Stor2rrd?

Tags: software-installation, apache2, network-monitoring

I'm new to Linux. I need to install Stor2rrd and I'm trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.stor2rrd.com/install.htm?1.2#debian)

I'm confused about where I put that sentence in `apache2.conf`:

[image]

Comment: `vi` is too complex for new users. Use `nano` or any other  text editor. If you wanna use GUI, use `gksu gedit` or `pkexec gedit`

Answer (score 2):

Lumping Debian and Ubuntu together is slightly strange. They are similar but not quite the same.

[a2enmod](http://man.he.net/man8/a2enmod) is a script unique to the Debian based distros. Essentially `a2enmod cgi` looks for files called cgi.load or cgi.conf and symlinks them from `/etc/apache2/mods-available` for available modules, to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` for enabled modules. You may need to restart apache after this.

`vi` is a text editor. People prefer it cause you almost always have vi on most systems. `nano` is a better option for a new user - its simpler and doesn't have some of the quirks vi does.

Personally if you're unsure what you're doing, I'd recommend starting with `sudo cp /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.bak` - so if you mess up, you have a known good copy of apache's config

Since this is Ubuntu and not Debian, you will want to invoke it with `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Ubuntu definitely has nano. Nano works a lot more like any other text editor you're familiar with. You need `sudo` cause I suspect the Debian instructions assume root is in use, Ubuntu has no password for the root account and sudo is the right way to do it. It elevates permissions just to run the command more or less, which is more secure.

I'm connected over putty and copy/paste works (and if you're new, connecting via ssh  from a gui enabled terminal is smart). Copy and paste these lines to the end of the file, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> exits, prompting you to save. Save, restart apache, and carry on